# How to print the initial hash and actual hash entry position for each entry

Tags: java, hashtable

I tried adding print statements in the (put) method of HashTable to print the initial hash and actual hash entry for each entry everytime the program runs. But i couldnt do it. My HashTable is using linear probing and i have attached the code (put method). Please help me as i am pretty new to programming so any help will be much appreciated.
`

```
    int hashIdx = hash(inKey);
    int initIdx = hashIdx;
    int i = 1;

    while (hashArray[hashIdx] != null && !hashArray[hashIdx].getKey().equals(inKey)) {

        if (!hashArray[hashIdx].getKey().equals(inKey)) { 
            if (hashArray[hashIdx].getState() == 1) { 
                hashIdx = (initIdx + i) % hashArray.length; 
            }

            if (hashArray[hashIdx].getState() < 1) { 
                hashArray[hashIdx] = new HashEntry(inKey, inValue); 
                hashCount++; 
            }
        }
        i++; 
    } 

}``
```

Comment: *"You tried adding print statements ... but you couldn't"* -- so what happened when you tried?  What did your attempt look like?

Comment: it wasnt looping properly. So it just shows one initial hash and keeps on printing that till the hash size